# Why cant I register a new user in React, Express and AWS RDS MariaDB

Tags: reactjs, express, mariadb, amazon-rds

Can someone help me I can not add new user to a database on aws

index.js (server)

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "cos30049.cf26i4a4s0yp.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  user: "admin",
  password: "12345678",
  database: "nifty",
});

connection.connect();

// API endpoint to get all users
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  const query = "SELECT * FROM account";

  connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      return;
    }

    res.json({ users: results });
  });
});

app.get("/assets", (req, res) => {
  const query = `
    Select a2.assetID, a1.username, a2.name, a2.category, a2.publishDate, a2.amount, a2.price, a2.description
    From account a1
    Join assets a2
    On a1.accountID = a2.authorId
  `;

  connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      return;
    }

    res.json({ assets: results });
  });
});

app.post("/signup" , (req, res) => {
  const sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, password, firstName, lastName) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  const values = [req.body.userName, req.body.password, req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName];

  connection.query(sql, values, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).send("Error signing up");
      return;
    }

    // Send back the ID of the new user
    res.send(`${results.insertId}`);
  });
});


// Close the MySQL connection when the server shuts down
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  connection.end();
  process.exit();
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

registerPage.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import TOPOLOGY from "vanta/dist/vanta.topology.min"; // Import Vanta Topology for background effect
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Button, Avatar, Grid, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; // Import useHistory
import Fade from '@mui/material/Fade';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import axios from 'axios';

function RegisterPage() {
    const history = useHistory(); // Access the history object for navigation

    const loginBackgroundRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loginBackgroundRef.current) {
            TOPOLOGY({
                el: loginBackgroundRef.current,
                mouseControls: true,
                touchControls: true,
                gyroControls: false,
                minHeight: 200.00,
                minWidth: 200.00,
                scale: 1.00,
                scaleMobile: 1.00,
                color: 0x8a8a8a,
                backgroundColor: 0x0
            });
        }
    }, []);

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        userName: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/signup', {
            username: values.userName,
            password: values.password,
            firstName: values.firstName,
            lastName: values.lastName,
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Registered successfully");
                history.push('/'); // Navigate to the home page after successful registration
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("Error registering"));
    };

    return (
        <Box ref={loginBackgroundRef} sx={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Box sx={{ width: "50vw", height: "0vh", display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around", alignItems: "center", borderRadius: "30px", backdropFilter: "blur(2px)", backgroundColor: "#161616a6" }}>
                <Fade in={true} timeout={1500}>
                    <Box
                        sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", gap: 2, alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                        <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                            <LockOutlinedIcon sx={{ fill: "#2a2a2a" }} />
                        </Avatar>
                        <h1>
                            Sign Up
                        </h1>
                        <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                    <TextField
                                        autoComplete="given-name"
                                        name="firstName"
                                        required
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        fullWidth
                                        id="firstName"
                                        label="First Name"
                                        autoFocus
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        fullWidth
                                        id="lastName"
                                        label="Last Name"
                                        name="lastName"
                                        autoComplete="family-name"
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        fullWidth
                                        id="userName"
                                        label="Username"
                                        name="userName"
                                        autoComplete="userName  "
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        required
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        fullWidth
                                        name="password"
                                        label="Password"
                                        type="password"
                                        id="password"
                                        autoComplete="new-password"
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center", mt: 2, gap: 2 }}>
                                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                                    Sign Up
                                </Button>
                                <Link to={'/login'} variant="body2" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                                    Already have an account? Sign in
                                </Link>
                            </Box>
                        </form>
                    </Box>
                </Fade>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

I have tried modifying and fixing both files and test connection before and after, checking the data insertion and nothing seems to work. The connection is fine since my network is very strong but I can not insert a single new user.

Please help me.